# SharePoint App permissions

Tags: sharepoint-addin, app-permissions

According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142383.aspx#Perm_types) MSDN link, each permission scope includes children of the particular scope.  To what extent is "children" defined? Is it limited to only lists and list items of the website, or does it include subsites of the website and lists/list items belonging to the subsites?  For example, an app with read permissions on web scope is installed to `https://somesite`.  Can it read lists/list items at `https://somesite/subsite`?

Comment: Yes if the subsite inherits permission from parent.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will access everything under neath it.If an app is granted permission to one of the scopes, the permission applies to all children of the scope.

> For example, if an app is granted permission to a website, the app is
>   also granted permission to each list that is contained in the website,
>   and all list items that are in each list.

Only way when it will not access the child if you have unique permission( break inheritance on child).

Comment: This includes subsites?

Comment: correct.If app get the permission on site collection and no unique permission on subsite then app will access everything.

Comment: Just to clarify, in order to get access to the subsites, then you need the site collection scope?

Comment: if you need access to subsite only then you need that subsite scope but if you need all subsite in a give site collection then you need site collection scope.